# Tailwind: add gap to flex without breaking row

Tags: css, flexbox, tailwind-css

I have a simple flex div with many children. I want 3 elements on each row using tailwindcss.

Is there a way to accomplish this using just tailwindcss classes? I tried with gap-4 on my parent div and child elements with w-1/3, but it adds margin to the children elements, breaking the row after the second element:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.7/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="flex flex-wrap gap-4  mb-6">
        <div class="w-1/3 shadow border rounded p-4">
            My element
        </div>
        <div class="w-1/3 shadow border rounded p-4">
            My element
        </div>
        <div class="w-1/3 shadow border rounded p-4">
            My element
        </div>
        <div class="w-1/3 shadow border rounded p-4">
            My element
        </div>
    </div>
```

How can I add a gap between the child elements, breaking the line only after every third element (in short: I want a 3 column div)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a grid job

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.7/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="grid-cols-3 grid gap-4  mb-6">
        <div class="shadow border rounded p-4">
            My element
        </div>
        <div class="shadow border rounded p-4">
            My element
        </div>
        <div class="shadow border rounded p-4">
            My element
        </div>
        <div class="shadow border rounded p-4">
            My element
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: If I recall correctly, this solution isn't responsive when fluid and Tailwind grid does not support fluid responsive grids.

Comment: Gap is also a flex box property so it would be good if this answer included a flex-based solution or mentioned whether or not Tailwind supports gap for flex-box.

Comment: @TomášHübelbauer not sure what are you talking about but this answer is not about *gap*. It's about implementing something using CSS grid instead of flexbox because CSS grid is more suitable. Also no one said Gap is not supported in Felxbox

Comment: we are looking for an answer that includes flex box not grid!

Comment: Is it possible to make the last row item's occupy whatever space is available? 1 full, 2 half, etc.

Answer (score 8):

You can customize the Tailwind CSS and add new class that calculates the basis including gaps.

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/flex-basis#using-custom-values

```
  theme: {
    extend: {
      flexBasis: {
        "1/3-gap-4": "calc(33.3% - (2/3 * 1rem))"
      }
    },
  },
```

and apply it with

```
<div class="flex flex-wrap gap-4">
        <div class="basis-1/3-gap-4">
            My element
        </div>
        <div class="basis-1/3-gap-4">
            My element
        </div>
        <div class="basis-1/3-gap-4">
            My element
        </div>
        <div class="basis-1/3-gap-4">
            My element
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You also can use the space between utility `space-x-{amount}` if you want to keep using `flex` instead of `grid`:

```
<div class="flex flex-wrap space-x-0 md:flex-nowrap md:space-x-4 ...">
  <div>01</div>
  <div>02</div>
  <div>03</div>
</div>
```

[More details here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/space)

> I've updated this answer to use flexbox. The key is adding the breaking points for flex-wrap and flex-nowrap.

Comment: To me this solution break the row as like as the gap (with flex-wrap).

Comment: You might be using it in the wrong way. If you are using margin or padding to have more gap/space between columns it will break the layout. Please refer to the "More details" link to see how to use it correctly.

Comment: This has the same issue as the original post. As soon as you add flex-wrap, to make it "responsive", it breaks immediately after the second column. -1

Comment: Yes. that's exactly how it works. Please read the docs to understand the basics and differences between the usage of the Tailwing Grid and Flexbox: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/space#limitations. I just gave an option to use with `display:flex` assuming the person knows how to use Flexbox and its perks.